# x-.y And what about intersection?

Tags: j

`x-.y` includes all items of x except for those that are cells of y 
But what if I want to get all items that are cells of x and of y? 
I can achieve this by

```
x -.^:2 y
```

But it require running expensive operation twice.
Is there a better solution?

Comment: Doing `-.` twice is note expensive. `-.` is rather efficient.

Answer (score 4):

`e.` is often useful when working with sets.

```
x e. y
```

gives a list of matches:

> for each item of x return `1` if it exists in the "set" y, `0` otherwise.

```
1 2 3 4 e. 5 9 2
0 1 0 0
```

Then,

```
x (e. # [) y
```

selects those elements that do exist in both lists.

```
1 2 3 4 (e. # [) 5 9 2
2
5 8 (e. # [) i.12
5 8
```

Comment: `-.^:2` seems more efficient by the way.

Answer (score 4):

Doing `-.` twice is the classic way of implementing intersection in J.

The inefficiency is minor (a constant factor - and, in general, you should not concern yourself with efficiency issues in J unless they exceed a factor of 2 - when you have resource problems you're generally going to want to focus on the factor of 1000 or greater issues).

Put differently, if `([-.-.)` or `-.^:2` is too slow for you then `-.` would also be too slow for you. (This can happen on extremely large data sets where the underlying implementation has been inefficient. Recent versions of J have had some work done, to correct this issue.)

Disappointing, perhaps, but practical.